# Windows 8.1 phone cordova application restarts when tried to resume from start screen

Tags: c#, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

When I go to splash screen from my application and try to open it from the app icon, the application restarts instead of resuming.
The following code works for silver light apps (**WNAppManifest.xml**):

`<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>`

In my case I only have **Package.appxmanifest.xml** and I am not able to use attribute **ActivationPolicy="Resume"**, may be it does not support here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S: sorry for bad english.

Thanks

Comment: I have seen this issue in my cordova project.